# can't get perspective to work on custom neon-animation in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to create my own opening door animation in Polymer but I can't get the `perspective` to work. My `animationConfig` looks like this:

```
animationConfig: {
  value: function() {
    return {
      testTransform: {
        name: 'transform-animation',
        node: this.$.door,
        transformFrom: 'rotateY(0deg) perspective(300)',
        transformTo: 'rotateY(-110deg) perspective(300)'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then a couple of methods:

```
doorClick: function() {
  console.log("clicked the door")
  if (!this.opened) {
    this.open()
  } else {
    this.close()
  }
},

open: function() {
  this.opened = true;
  this.playAnimation('testTransform');
}
```

if I put only the `rotateY` in `transformFrom` and `transformTo` the rotation works but not with the perspective and perspective alone doesn't work either. I don't get any error in the console either.

Answer (score 0):

I added the perspective property to the parent element instead of the element I was animating.